# Python 3.4.x Install Via TGZ on Windows 10

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I searched this and it's always about Linux operating systems and I'm unable to see any videos or tutorial sites.

I have windows 10 64x based os and I plan to use Python 3.4.x (https://www.python.org/downloads/) for me to use the old cx_freeze (https://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.3.3/) since I have this video tutorial in youtube I am currently following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHcDHSWRCRQ which is a python 3 tutorial to create exe file.

The latest cx_freeze file uses `.whl` files that is so inconvenient for me and I won’t be able to follow the youtube tutorial mentioned above to create a `.exe` file for my python, thus went on the old cx_freeze that works https://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.3.3/ where latest version is for python 3.4. The tutorial on the video has the same cx_freeze process to create a `.exe` file even if it's for python 3.2.

Also, I don't see any installer of Python 3.4 on it's official page but TGZ files only. I searched about how to use TGZ files on Windows but it's just about extracting and nothing else, while other tutorials on how to install it are all linux based.

How do install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [legacy Python website](https://legacy.python.org) has official downloads for 3.4.0 including a [Windows installer](https://legacy.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/python-3.4.0.msi). You should be able to grab the .msi from there and that will fix your issue!

Comment: Thank you so much ! XD that did it ! i had successfully followed the video tutorial of cx_freeze also, had my my python executable app works everywhere on windows hahaha! thanks again :)